# Задание столбцу множественного значения

Tags: mysql, массивы, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица `features`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и таблица `monoblocks`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно организовать хранение в поле `monoblocks.feature_id` списка айдишников из таблицы `features` (желательно привести пример)?

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае Вам лучше хранить данные в промежуточной таблице monoblocks_features, со следующими полями:

- `id` -> Тут всё понятно
- `monoblock_id` -> ID записи в таблице `monoblocks`
- `feature_id` -> ID записи в таблице `features`

Привязывайте к конкретному monoblocks.id сколько угодно features.id, и получайте данные:

```sql
SELECT `feature_id` FROM `monoblocks_features` WHERE `monoblock_id` = 12;
```

Так Вы получите все features.id, которые привязаны к конкретному monoblocks.id